# Response time monitoring location

Tags: monitoring

Why the reponse time of a given Web service changes from a monitoring location to another?
Why in some monitoring tools they give the reponse time according to differnet monitoring location? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer would be that the further the server is away from the point of access, the more ISPs the information has to travel through. If you are in China accessing a server (website) in the US, it wouldn't be a direct route and you're at the mercy of whomever owns the wires that information is traveling through.